# Remove WPF IsDefault

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have 3 conrtols placed on my `Window` in WPF, each control contains one or more `TextBox` and `Button`, when a new control is selected I would like to change the `IsDefault` to that button. What I am currently doing is when the `TextBox`'s `GotFocus` event is fired, I change my `Button` to `IsDefault`. This works the first time but when I change from one control to another, and back to the first selected control the second controls `IsDefault` is still true and when enter is pressed it fires the `Click` event on the incorrect control.

Is there a way that i can clear all `IsDefault` properties on my window or what is a better solution to my current way of doing this? See image below for example, when enter is pressed the `Button` with "..." is fired instead of quick search.

[image]

XAML (Update)

```
 <odc:OdcTextBox Text="{Binding AccountNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="100" Name="txtAccountNumber" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="{Binding TextMargin}">
        <odc:OdcTextBox.Buttons>
            <Button IsDefault="{Binding ElementName=txtAccountNumber, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource DionysusButton}" x:Name="btnCdv" Content="...">

            </Button>
        </odc:OdcTextBox.Buttons>
    </odc:OdcTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to how you're using the `TextBox` `GotFocus` event, you could do the inverse of this and use the `LostFocus` event to reset the `IsDefault` Property

Comment: Maybe not the best solution but it works  perfectly, using the binding like in the other answer would've been ideal but it works! Thanx

Comment: Agree that it isn't the best solution and the other answer is definitely more elegant which is why I upvoted that one. It's a shame you couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button IsDefault={Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=ThisGroupBox} />
```

EDIT:

Your code is slightly different in that you are providing buttons to some custom control. These buttons are declared in a different scope to where they end up (ie I assume they end up inside the OdcTextBox template somewhere). I suspect this is why WPF can't find the named element since that element is named in an outer scope.

You could try using `RelativeSource` to find the parent `OdcTextBox` instead:

```
<Button IsDefault="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type odc:OdcTextBox}}}" 
        Width="30" Style="{StaticResource DionysusButton}" x:Name="btnCdv" Content="...">
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not seem to work either. When I switch to the second control the `IsDefault` does not work ie enter does not trigger the `Click`.

Comment: I found this in my output window:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=txtAccountNumber'. BindingExpression:Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='btnCdv'); target property is 'IsDefault' (type 'Boolean')

Comment: Can you post a xaml snippet of the bit in question?

Comment: Still no luck. System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Odyssey.Controls.OdcTextBox', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='btnCdv'); target property is 'IsDefault' (type 'Boolean')